# What does the phrase "prospects were beginning to chirp back" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What does the last sentence mean?

> "But I slowly started to notice a change. Clients were increasingly respondent to my emails. Even prospects were beginning to chirp back more times than not".

[Source](https://medium.com/@InVisionApp/the-right-way-to-end-an-email-to-a-client-9aa92f13fcc9#.94vitijtr)

I found one definition in Urban dictionary, but it doesn't seem appropriate:

> "to holler back to someone using a nextel, making it make a "chirping" noise".

Then I tried to look for "***chirp***" definition in Merriam Webster:

> : to make a short high-pitched sound
>
> : to say (something) in a cheerful and lively way

Comment: Try looking up *chirp* in a proper dictionary.

Comment: It looks to me like meaning "a short phone call".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reasons unknown, I am unable to access the reference link provided by you.

Nonetheless, I can infer that the article is about how to write e-mails to customers.

You seem to have problems in interpreting the expression - "***to chirp back***".

As you've pointed out, the ODO defines ***[chirp](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/chirp)*** as

> (Of a person) say something in a lively and cheerful way

In this context, it simply refers to a ***response***. Whether it was cheerful or lively, as readers, we are not concerned.

Taking the sentence in question,

> But I slowly started to notice a change. Clients were increasingly respondent to my emails. Even prospects were beginning to chirp back more times than not.

The author is probably giving out e-mail etiquette/ writing tips when sending mails to customers. By following those, the author noticed that customers, who generally don't respond to e-mails soliciting their feedback or product promotions (e-mail of *any* kind, for that fact!), start to respond to them and even "prospects"(potential customers of a business) were starting to reply to messages and perhaps reacting to promotional campaigns("chirping back"). *More times than not* means "often" or "frequently".